# labview using advantech dll : memory leak ? + Bluescreen

Tags: dll, memory-leaks, flush, labview

I'm currently using several advantech devices with LabView, 
When I use one function with the dll it use memory, if I call it several time the memory used increased over and over ... to finally crash labview or have a bluescreen.

I've tried to flush the memory each time, it works better (crash after 30 min, before it was 10 sec ...)

Comment: You didn't give enough details to get an answer. If it is your code, please provide it. If not, this is probably not the right place to ask.

Comment: It's just the use of the DAQNavi advantech VI which produce the problem, I've isolated the problem.
I was wondering if there was an existing solution to avoid crash from the dll ... Thanks

Comment: Could you add a snippet of your code?

Comment: http://support.advantech.com.tw/Support/DownloadSRDetail_New.aspx?SR_ID=1-FCIIF6&Doc_Source=Download with the "DAQNavi_SDK and Drivers_3.1.9.0.exe" the problem is made with the "DAQNavi Assistant" express VI, I've tried simulation withtout the hardware device : same pipe, same dll calls and no crash.

Comment: image link : http://hpics.li/e502ee1
this is inside the section called by the hardware (or the simulation)
I get an error at the "Control Set Config" which is just a dll Call ...

Comment: here is the snippet : http://hpics.li/25fa218 
just the Advantech VI, configured for 4716 device with crash or in simulation : no crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after a few weeks :

There was a software memory leak in the manufacturer DLL. Changed my way of measuring to avoid the problem.
There was only a few % of people having this problem